# Excel CommandButton names changing

Tags: excel, vba, commandbutton

I created an excel file with macros on *ActiveX-CommandButtons*. 
They worked well, when I just finished them. 
As soon as I opened the file again, the **CommandButton-Names changed**.

---

As example:

CommandButton1 changed to CommandButton2

CommandButton2 changed to CommandButton3
etc.

---

I didn't found anything in my reasearch, so is this an excel bug or just something that you can change in your preferences?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on CommandButton

Go to (click on) 'Format Text Effects'

Give the name to button, whichever you want.

Save it.

Close the workbook.

Open it back and check whether name changes

(No need to enable 'Design Mode')

It works for me. Hope it shall work for you too.

If it do not work then please let me know.

For more info: https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-in/article/Add-a-button-and-assign-a-macro-to-it-in-a-worksheet-d58edd7d-cb04-4964-bead-9c72c843a283?CorrelationId=345214f6-6d01-4b07-994b-b2e33159e694&ui=en-US&rs=en-IN&ad=IN

Comment: I tried that before. When I specifically name them, they just change to CommandButton1, CommandButton2 etc...

Comment: While doing it, had you checked your 'Design Mode'?

Please go through the link I added in answer :)

Comment: Yes, I activated design mode. Also try to recreate the button but this ain't solving the problem.

Comment: Did you change the Caption property rather than the Name property?

Comment: No, I changed the actual name property and therefore I had to adjust the function name as well. It then worked properly again, but when I restarted excel again, it was gone, the name changed back. And I saved the file, so this shouldn't be an issue as well.

I also rebooted the PC, no change...

Comment: I have changed/ edited my answer; Check it. Had you tried the same or something else to change button name?

Comment: This would possibly work, if the button wouldn't be an ActiveX-Button. Mine is one. I adjusted the OP, so that it is clear.